# Ошибка при подключении к игровой комнате реализованной с помощью Pun Photon

Tags: unity3d

Я создал UI в Unity [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и у меня возникает ошибка

```
"CreateRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking)but not ready for operations (State: PeerCreated). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:CreateRoom (string,Photon.Realtime.RoomOptions,Photon.Realtime.TypedLobby,string[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:1782)
MainMenu:CreateRoom () (at Assets/Scripts/MainMenu.cs:18)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)"
```

после того, как я пытаюсь зайти в созданную игровую комнату. Как это можно исправить. Если надо, я могу скинуть код

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо подключиться к мастер-серверу. В данный момент, как я понимаю, вы пытаетесь подключится к случайной комнате без подключения к мастер-серверу.